# Gas errored in remix

Tags: web3js, contract-development, remix, polygon, solidity-0.8.x

HELLO I AM PRACTICING WITH SOLIDITY AND I HAVE A GAS ESTIMATION ERROR IN REMIX. SOMEONE GUIDE ME WHY THIS HAPPENS IN MY CONTRACT I WILL PROVIDE IT THERE
PD: compiles OK

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Proyect0x is ERC20, ERC20Burnable, Pausable, Ownable {

    uint256 private immutable _maxSupply;
    uint256 private immutable _preMint;
    uint256 private _totalLocked;
    mapping(address => uint256) private _lockedBalances;
    mapping(address => uint256) private _lockTimestamps;
    address private constant _DEAD_ADDRESS = 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD;
    event TokensLocked(address indexed account, uint256 amount, uint256 unlockTimestamp);
    event TokensUnlocked(address indexed account, uint256 amount, uint256 reward);
    event TokensBurned(address indexed account, uint256 amount, uint256 reward);
    
    constructor() ERC20("Proyect0x", "P0x") {
        uint8 decimals = ERC20(this).decimals();
        _maxSupply = 44000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));
        _preMint = 20000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));
        _mint(_msgSender(), _preMint);
    }

    function pause() public onlyOwner {
        _pause();
    }

    function unpause() public onlyOwner {
        _unpause();
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        require(totalSupply() + amount <= _maxSupply, "Max supply exceeded");
        _mint(to, amount);
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount)
        internal
        whenNotPaused
        override
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
        require(balanceOf(from) - amount >= _lockedBalances[from], "Tokens are locked");
    }

    function lockTokens(uint256 amount) public {
        require(amount > 0, "Amount cannot be zero");
        require(balanceOf(_msgSender()) >= amount, "Insufficient balance");

        uint256 unlockTimestamp = block.timestamp + 30 days;
        _transfer(_msgSender(), address(this), amount);

        _totalLocked += amount;
        _lockedBalances[_msgSender()] += amount;
        _lockTimestamps[_msgSender()] = unlockTimestamp;

        emit TokensLocked(_msgSender(), amount, unlockTimestamp);
    }

    function unlockTokens() public {
        require(_lockedBalances[_msgSender()] > 0, "No tokens locked");
        require(block.timestamp >= _lockTimestamps[_msgSender()], "Tokens are still locked");

        uint256 amount = _lockedBalances[_msgSender()];
        _totalLocked -= amount;
        _lockedBalances[_msgSender()] = 0;

        uint256 reward = amount * 12 / 100;
        _mint(_msgSender(), reward);

        emit TokensUnlocked(_msgSender(), amount, reward);
    }

    function getLockTime(address account) public view returns (uint256) {
        if (_lockTimestamps[account] == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return _lockTimestamps[account] - block.timestamp;
    }

   function getTotalLocked() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _totalLocked;
    }

    function burn(uint256 amount) public override {
        require(amount > 0, "Amount must be greater than 0");

        uint256 burnAmount = balanceOf(msg.sender) < amount ? balanceOf(msg.sender) : amount;

        uint256 reward = burnAmount * 20 / 100;

        _burn(msg.sender, burnAmount);
        _mint(_DEAD_ADDRESS, burnAmount);

        _mint(msg.sender, reward);

        emit TokensBurned(msg.sender, burnAmount, reward);
    }

    function emergencyWithdraw() public onlyOwner {
        _mint(msg.sender, balanceOf(address(this)));
        _totalLocked = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What function were you calling, and what parameter were you using?

Comment: to several functions there is the complete contract basically what it does is give rewards for holding and burning by calling a mint function that is independent of premint